# Can I save my data while reinstalling Ubuntu again?

Tags: 18.04, backup, disk-usage

I'm having some trouble with wifi driver, so I'm reinstalling ubuntu 18.04. I currently have the same LTS version. I have some videos of size 100gb. How can I save that? Is there an option ubuntu gives while reinstalling? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, simply don't format the drive. However, humans make mistakes and unexpected events occur, and data sometimes get unintentionally deleted. If you truly value that data, back it up.

Comment: You should backup the data before any new installation. One (rather clever) approach for a new install is creating a new partition for this 100GB of data - a separate partition(a data partition), because in this case you could just install a new system on the other partition and leave the data partition untouched.

Answer (score 0):

During the Ubuntu setup there is an option to reinstall Ubuntu. Select that option and continue with your installation, you won't have to suffer any data loss.